# Highlight the currently selected TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native, highlight, textinput, selected

I'd like to highlight the currently selected TextInput by changing the borderColor. I'm aware of the onFocus and onBlur properties, however, I can't figure out how to actually change the borderColor.

```
const MainScreen = () => {
   const [pelletWeight, setPelletWeight] = React.useState('');
   onFocus = () => {
        console.log("Text is focused")
    }
    
    onBlur = () => {
        console.log("Text is blurred")
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.root}>
                            
            <TextInput 
            style = {styles.container}
            keyboardType='numeric'
            placeholder="Pellet weight (grains)"
            onChangeText={setPelletWeight}
            value={pelletWeight}
            
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            />
    )
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need a piece of state to keep track of whether the input is focused or not. Lets called it `isFocused`. Use `onBlur` and `onFocus` to set its values. Now you create your focused textinput style. It will  be added to the style only when `isFocused` is true:

```js
 const [pelletWeight, setPelletWeight] = React.useState('');
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = React.useState(false);
  onFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };

  onBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <Text style={[styles.baseText]}>Pellet Weight (grains)</Text>

      <TextInput
        style={[styles.container, isFocused && styles.focusedInput]}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        placeholder="Pellet weight (grains)"
        onChangeText={setPelletWeight}
        value={pelletWeight}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/zHy0BNQQ3)

Now if you wanted to take things a step further, instead of the border width, border color, and background color instantly changing, you could use react native reanimated to make the transition happen smoothly:

```js
  const [pelletWeight, setPelletWeight] = React.useState('');
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = React.useState(false);
  const anim = useSharedValue(0);
  onFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };

  onBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  };
  const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      borderWidth: anim.value,
      backgroundColor: interpolateColor(
        anim.value,
        [0, 1],
        ['transparent', 'lightblue']
      ),
      borderColor: interpolateColor(
        anim.value,
        [0, 1],
        ['transparent', 'blue']
      ),
    };
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    anim.value = withTiming(isFocused? 1 : 0)
  }, [isFocused,anim]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <Text style={[styles.baseText]}>Pellet Weight (grains)</Text>

      <AnimatedTextInput
        style={[styles.container, styles.focusedInput,animStyle]}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        placeholder="Pellet weight (grains)"
        onChangeText={setPelletWeight}
        value={pelletWeight}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/FZhwyRCG3o)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Now I'm going to figure out how to make it work with my Light Mode/Dark Mode style sheets.

Comment: It works perfectly for one TextInput, but with more added, they all seem to get highlighted at once. Am I going to need to add additional variables for each TextInput?

Comment: If will need to create a seperate textninput component or otherwise each textinput will need its own `isFocused`, 'anim`. and animatedStyle